# debsums flags some files as broken even after package reinstallation

Tags: package-management

When I run `debsums -c` in ubuntu it flags the following files as corrupted:

```
/usr/lib/aspell/it.rws 
/var/lib/aspell/it.compat
```

Trough `dpkg -S` I discovered that those two files belong to the package `aspell-it` (italian dictionary for GNU Aspell). After reinstallig it debsums says they's still corrupted.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

(Apologies - I don't have enough reputation to add comments)

Could you explain how you reinstalled the `aspell-it`. Also can you display the exact output of `dpkg -S /usr/lib/aspell/it.rws` and `dpkg -S /var/lib/aspell/it.compat`

### You can try doing the following:

- Uninstall `aspell-it`

> sudo apt-get remove aspell-it

- Now check that the files `/usr/lib/aspell/it.rws` and `/var/lib/aspell/it.compat` are gone. If yes then reinstall:

> sudo apt-get install aspell-it

- Now try `debsums -c` again and check if you are still facing the same issue.